# Is this code for emptying a linked list okay?

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, nodes, reset

I need to work on a function that resets a linked list without completely eliminating it, and I wanted to know if my piece of code is right. Any other suggestions?

```
        void reset(){
        if (initial == nullptr){
            return;
        }
        Node<T> *flag;
        Node<T> *temp;
        while(initial->obtainNext() != nullptr){
            flag = initial->();
            temp = flag->obtainNext();
            delete flag;
            inicial->setNext(temp);
        }
        initial->setNext(nullptr);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: You have some typos. What does it mean to "reset" a linked list? If you are emptying it, why wouldn't you "completely eliminate" it?

Comment: So it looks like `Reset()` goes through each item in the list and deletes it then unlinks it. Anyway, if you are looking for a code review, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean by `reset`, do you want to erase all node in a linked list or initialize 0 or `'\0'` to all linked list nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By my understanding you're trying to erase your linked list.
1. You may just loop through the given node and delete all of them setting the head node as nullptr.
2. You may make an object which holds that linked list and may serve your purpose by using method 1 in erasing everybody but the object still exists with a variable set to nullptr.

Comment: Thanks, that´s what I did (first option), was just missing like 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have already implemented `pop_back()` \ `pop_front()` \ `erase()` method in your class so it is possible to not write some new additional logic but use existing one with any loop as followed:

```
void clear 
{
while(this->size) //can be class field which indicates list's size or call size() method
    this->pop_front();// can be changed as mentioned above
}
```